# How to run bundletool, aapt2

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been reading [Build your .aab using bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build) recently, and downloaded bundletool and aapt2 tools as per guidance provided. But, I'm having problem running both tools.
I tried to run bundletool with the command:

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\bundletool\0.7.2\bundletool-0.7.2.jar"
```

and get the error

```
no main manifest attribute, in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\bundletool\0.7.2\bundletool-0.7.2.jar
```

Run aapt2 with the command

```
java -jar C:\aapt2\aapt2-3.2.0-rc01-4818971-windows.jar compile --dir C:\test_aab\res -o C:\test_aab\compiled_resource
```

and, the error is the same

```
no main manifest attribute, in C:\aapt2\aapt2-3.2.0-rc01-4818971-windows.jar
```

What am I doing wrong here ?, is it because of my Java version

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing a similar issue.